# Spider closes down on getting multiple failed URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

Recently, I had to scrape a huge list of URLs from which many of them failed to load, took too long to load, did not exist etc.

My spider closes automatically when it gets a series of such broken URLs.
How can I change that behavior and ask it to not sweat bullets at the URLs that fail but simply jump over them.

Here is my ugly error trace :

```
Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 949, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 702, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    transport = connection.get_app_data()
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1224, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 838, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'

From callback <function infoCallback at 0x7feaa9e3a8c0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 702, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1059, in infoCallback
    connection.get_app_data().failVerification(f)
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1224, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 838, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'
```

Apart from the above error that I do not understand, I also get a lot `TimeoutError`s and twisted failures.

```
2015-10-05 12:30:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.example.com> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>>]
```

What is the error about ? Why does my spider close on getting these ? How can I change that ?

Answer (score 3):

The first error is that there is a bug in scrapy: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1227

It may be solved with installing `service_identity`:

```
pip install service_identity
```

The second problem is that twisted cannot connect to the example domain. In this case there is nothing to do because the URLs are skipped without any problem -- it is only logged that there is nothing at the other end. I think this has nothing to do with your spider shutting down but the error you get because of the mentioned bug.

Comment: After I get a dozen such failures, the spider closes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/darshanime/16ab4bb86c11151a494e) are my stats. I fed the URLs from an excel file, they were thousands of them.

Comment: I do not know for sure but if your thousands of URLs are from those sites where you get the DNSLookupError then it might be that scrapy knows that the given domain is not available and doesn't even try to crawl those URLs. Again: I am not sure but I suspect this is happening.

Comment: Nope, that is not it. All my URLs are from different domains. There is something else at play here. I wonder what.